# Database not being created by Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating a project management app using a tutorial. No database is being created. I've set breakpoints in every place I can think of, and none of them are being hit. However, the project compiles. I've even tried changing the models to trigger database creation.

I have:

TaskContext.cs

```
public class TaskContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TaskDetail> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }  
}
```

TaskInitializer.cs:

```
public class TaskInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TaskContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(TaskContext context)
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { EmployeeName = "James Dean" },
            new Employee { EmployeeName = "Linda Berry" }
        };
        foreach (var temp in employees)
        {
            context.Employees.Add(temp);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        var statuses = new List<Status>
        {
            new Status {StatusName = "Open"},
            new Status {StatusName = "Code Reveiw"}
        };
        foreach (var temp in statuses)
        {
            context.Statuses.Add(temp);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        var tasks = new List<TaskDetail>
        {
            new TaskDetail {TaskName="Learn c#", TaskDescription="Learn C# from Video", AssignDate=DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015"), EmployeeId=1, StatusId=2},
            new TaskDetail {TaskName="Learn MVC", TaskDescription="Learn MVC Using Sample Projects", AssignDate=DateTime.Parse("02/02/2015"), EmployeeId=1, StatusId=1}
        };
        foreach (var temp in tasks)
        {
            context.Tasks.Add(temp);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

My Web.config has:

```
<add name="TaskContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TaskProject.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TaskProject-20150515093801;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My global.asax has:

```
Database.SetInitializer<TaskContext>(new TaskInitializer());
```

Employee.cs:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

Status.cs:

```
public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
}
```

TaskDetail.cs

```
public class TaskDetail
{
    public int TaskDetailId { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime AssignDate { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status status { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee employee { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you run the commands on the Package manager Console to update your DB?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Actually I'm following a tutorial that does not mention doing that. Is there anything that might be missing from my existing code?

Comment: You need to update your DB schema with the new updates you made to your models. you need to run a command to achieve that since this is a Code-First approach.
Here are the steps , but you need to learn more about this process:
in your VS:
- Tools -> Library Package Manager ->Package Manager Console
In the command line type these commands in order:
1- Enable-Migrations
2- Add-Migration 'Name of your migration' ==== you can change the name to reflect what are you doing; for instance : "First DB design"
3- Update-Database
If everything is OK your database will be updated with your tables

Comment: Run  Database.Initialize(true);  after  Database.SetInitializer<TaskContext>(new TaskInitializer()); http://www.codeitive.com/7mzSUVXUek/can-you-create-a-database-without-migrations-in-ef5.html

Comment: @SteveGreene, I got `Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Data.Entity.Database.Initialize(bool)'`

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker, I created a similar project earlier using the same video series (actually questions about it are asked commonly on SO because the first video is on youtube). The database was created. I don't think there should be any problem with what I'm doing without using a console. I'm convinced there is some simple problem with my code because I've set breakpoints all over the place, and although it's compiling, NONE of them are getting hit.

Comment: Try moving both statements to the static constructor of your context: static TaskContext() { Database.SetInitializer<TaskContext>(new TaskInitializer());  Database.Initialize(true);  }

Comment: Also, in the link from @Steve Greene, it reads: "When I was looking at the EF 5 with Mvc 5 tutorial they didn't use migrations to create a database. They use database initializer. So, I was wondering could create a database for your project without using migrations in EF 5?" The answer given is: "YES you can "Create a Database without Migrations""

Comment: Sorry, Steve, where would I but that? After the DbSet's or before?

Comment: Constructors usually go at the top. I don't think that's your issue now that I see you are using localdb and accessing the context in your seed method (that should force database to initialize). Try delete the localdb and from the App_Data folder and rerunning. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118594/how-to-work-with-localdb-and-ef-without-using-migrations

Comment: @abalter i didnt say you cannot do it without migrations. MS recommends using manual migrations as it gives you more visibility and control on your models/DB.
Check this :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx
and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tips-when-making-changes-in-entity-framework-code-first-models-after-scaffolding.aspx

Comment: Ok, now this is WEIRD. First of all, I figured out that to hit my break points I need to be in debug mode, not just compiling. DUURRRR. So, I stepped through the entire application, and it actually worked. HOWEVER, there is still nothing in the App_Data folder. So it is displaying the data, but there does not appear to be a databse.

Comment: I'll look into using migrations. For now, I just need to learn how to build a basic app and make it work.